# Laravel doesn't get data from Postman

Tags: laravel, postman

I am starting work on an API in Laravel, using Postman. However, no matter what I send via Postman, the $request received is empty.

Route in Laravel:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'as' => 'api.'], function() {
    Route::post('/stock-list', 'DataController@stock_list');
});
```

Controller method:

```
public function stock_list(Request $request)
{
    logger()->info($request->all());
    return response()->json([
        'request' => $request
    ]);
}
```

The log shows that `$request->all()` is an empty array. Since I am also returning $request to Postman as a test, this is what Postman gets as a response:

```
{
    "request": {
        "attributes": {},
        "request": {},
        "query": {},
        "server": {},
        "files": {},
        "cookies": {},
        "headers": {}
    }
}
```

What am I sending? In Postman, I have this content in the body tab:

```
{
    'foo' : 'bar'
}
```

The body type is selected as `raw` and Postman reads it as `JSON`.

In terms of authentication, I have chosen `basic auth` with username and password for now, however I have not done anything on the Laravel side about this (as you can see from the route and controller). As far as I can tell, this shouldn't matter at this point - the request should still be received by Laravel correctly, then either an "unauthenticated" response should be returned, or no authentication should happen at all since there is no `auth` middleware on the route.

Can someone explain the cause of the problem and suggest a solution?

EDIT

Here are the headers in Postman:

[image]

Comment: Is your `Content-Type` header of the request is properly set to `application/json`?

Comment: No clue if `'request' => $request` includes all params, so you could change it too `'request' => $request->all()`

Comment: @Roland Starke `$request->all()` will add only the attributes, $request adds all as you can see in his response

Comment: @jovan When you select 'raw' in postman you need to click the dropdown and select json.

Comment: @bhucho I testet it, `'request' => $request, 'params' => $request->all(),` request is empty like in the question, only params contains `{'foo' : 'bar'}` (+ one needs the mentioned content-type header.)

Comment: Alternatively, you can debug it with curl if you have doubts concerning Postman : `curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{ 'foo' : 'bar' }" -v your_url`

Comment: show the image how are you posting data in postman ?  after selecting it to Raw, select json from the dropdown, and then try  !

Comment: @RemcoK. It is.

Comment: @ahmadizhar I already selected JSON from the dropdown.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://www.jasonsuave.com/sending-json-to-laravel-with-postman/

Comment: @RemcoK. As I said, the content-type is already set correctly.

Comment: @jovan already tested what this returns? $request->getContent()

Comment: @RemcoK. That returns `{ 'foo' : 'bar' }`, but for some reason `$request->all()` returns an empty array.

Comment: @jovan does `$request->input()` return the data?

Comment: Could you please show what headers are being sent by Postman. Also, could you try sending content as form data to see if that works?

Comment: @Qumber I added a screenshot of the headers to the question. When I send as form-data, the outcome is the same as with JSON.

Comment: Can you remove **all** headers including `Content-Type` and add one `Accept: application/json` and see if it does anything?

Comment: how you hosting your application? php artisan serve or a web server ?

Comment: @jovan Try changing `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` to `use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest as Request;` in your controller file or using `$request = request(); in your controller action`. and share whether data is received

Comment: $request->getContent(); Have you tried this one?

Comment: why you used  logger()->info($request->all());??
what is logger here?

Comment: can you share with us how you solve this problem
i have the same

Comment: @MohamdAlmhde I can't remember tbh, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    'foo' : 'bar'
}
```

is not a valid JSON. By standard you have to use double quotes.

```
{
    "foo" : "bar"
}
```

You already set content-type to json which is good. I believe it should be working now.

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand why you used logger()->info($request->all()); in your code but I tried your code like bellow and it worked

route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'Api'], function() {
Route::post('stock-list', 'Api\UsersControllers@stock_list');
});
```

controller:

```
 public function stock_list(Request $request)
{
    $request=$request->all();
    return response()->json([
        'request' => $request
    ]);
}
```

postmans:
[image]